# SQL Deployment task fail on activating Azure Active Directory authentication only

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, cicd

Hello I have a sql server getting deployed and pipeline uses SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 to deploy DB.

As part of security recommendation we need to turn on Support only Azure Active Directory authentication for this server in Azure Active Directory menu under Settings for SQL Server.

If I turn this on my deployment fails as my pipeline task uses SqlUserName and SqlPassword. How should I resolve this? Should I create a new generic login which is a AAD user or there is any other better alternative?

Please feel free to let me know if any additional information is required.

Main yaml

```
//parameters:

//trigger:
  
//variables: 
 
stages:
- stage: 
  jobs:
  - job: 
    workspace:
      clean: 
    pool:
      
    steps:
    
    - //tasks  
    
- template: templates\myTemplate.yaml
  parameters:
    //list of params
```

myTemplate

```
parameters:

stages:
- stage: 
  variables:
  
  pool:
    name: 
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy Azure Infra
    displayName: Deploy Azure Infra
    pool:
      name: 
    environment: 
      name: 
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - download: current
              artifact: drop              
                           
  //job      

  - job: Deploy Database
    dependsOn: 
    displayName: 
    steps:
      - download: current
        artifact: databases

      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: 'Disable'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: ''
          scriptType: ps
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: 'az sql server ad-only-auth disable --resource-group rg1 --name mySql'

      - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
        displayName: 
        inputs:          

      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: 'Enable'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: ''
          scriptType: ps
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: 'az sql server ad-only-auth enable --resource-group rg1 --name mySql'
```

Comment: I have tried to check the box and use different authentication type all of them seems to be failing with following message: {"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/MyDBModule","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","target":"/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/mysqlsvr"

Comment: "message":"The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.","details":[{"code":"AadOnlyAuthenticationIsEnabled","message":"Azure Active Directory Only Authentication is enabled. Please contact your system administrator."}]}]}

Comment: While authenticating with other methods disable "Azure Active Directory Only Authentication" and try again.

Comment: I did try let me update the yaml file details in the question. Please let me know if this is what you meant

Comment: @Bhavani I added yaml to the question and doing this as well failed with same error. My template yaml has the step to deploy azure infra which provisions the sql server and db's

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Creating a generic Azure AD user and adding it as an Admin of Azure SQL Server would help you in deploying dacpac with Azure **SqlAzureDacpacDeployment task**:-

***I added one Azure AD user as Admin of my azure SQL Server like below:-***

[image]

**My Azure yaml pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'devopsappsilicon'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az sql server ad-only-auth disable --resource-group pratikrg1 --name siliconserver'
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'devopsappsilicon'
    AuthenticationType: 'aadAuthenticationPassword'
    ServerName: 'siliconserver.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'silicondb'
    aadSqlUsername: 'test4@outlook.onmicrosoft.com'
    aadSqlPassword: 'Password'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Database1.dacpac'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'IPAddressRange'
    StartIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    EndIpAddress: '255.255.255.255'
    
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'devopsappsilicon'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: 'az sql server ad-only-auth enable --resource-group pratikrg1 --name siliconserver'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Pratik... My bicep module that provisions sql server is:                                     resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-11-01' = {
  name: ''
  location: 
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: ''
    administratorLoginPassword: ''
    version: '12.0'
  }
}    How do I update this?

Comment: Also I have an existing group which I would prefer rather than individual users set as admin. If we make the group as admin, how do I get the aadSqlPassword in SqlAzureDacpacDeployment task, I mean I do not know if group has password? And also how will the provisioning above change? Please let me know.

Comment: Is this ok?
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-11-01' = {
  name: 
  location: 
  properties: {    
    version: '12.0'
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      tenantId: subscription().tenantId
      principalType: 'Group'
      login: sqlAdminGroupName
      sid: sqlAdminGroupObjectId
    }
  }
}

Comment: Try the below coce in order to add group as principal for Azure AD SQL authentication 
`properties: {
    administratorLogin: 'string'
    administratorLoginPassword: 'string'
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
      login: 'string'
      principalType: 'Group'
      sid: 'string'
      tenantId: 'string'`

Comment: Make sure you add the group as an external user inside the Azure SQL after its deployment. Then try to log in with the users inside the group. 
Use this command to add group as Externnal user in Azure SQL `CREATE USER [AZ-Users] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` And user user Id as azure Ad userId and password as azure A user password

Comment: If I am going with administrator object is it required for me to still have administrator login and password as shown in your comment? Can you please tell me why? As I thought it will not be required. Also since I am using it for provisioning sql server and then the stage template will deploy dacpac. So I am not certain how do I add group as external user.

Comment: resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-11-01' = {
  name: ''
  location: resourceGroup().location  
  properties: {    
    version: '12.0'
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      tenantId: subscription().tenantId
      principalType: ''
      login: aadGroupName
      sid: ''
    }
  }
}

Param File
"aadGroupName": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/mykv"
        },
        "secretName": "MyAdGroupName"
      }
    }

Comment: The above did not work with the error message: {"code":"InvalidParameterValue","message":"Invalid value given for parameter Login. Specify a valid parameter value."}  I have the name of the group saved as secret in key vault

Comment: I came across another link today, seems like this an error for which only manual resolution is possible https://github.com/Azure/bicep-types-az/issues/1436